# No file in installed gem in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created my own gem and installed it locally. It was successfully installed but can't use. I checked my gem in gems folder. I found it but there is just only blank file.

Comment: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using **array** and added **all files** which I want to add at my **gem** in gemspec. Such below -

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|

s.files = [
    "MIT-LICENSE",
     "README",
     "Rakefile",
  ]

end
```

Comment: From the guide: `If you’ve added more files to your gem, make sure to remember to add them to your gemspec’s files array...`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for remind me. I already solved my errors with such way.

Answer (score 1):

The file shouldn't be blank, but it shouldn't be human readable either.  Follow the steps here:

http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Some things to consider:

1) The first thing shown in the tutorial is the tree command:

```
$ tree
```

...which is a little confusing.  You may or may not have that command.  You can install it if you want to.  The tree command just lists all the files in the current directory and all the subdirectories in a nice graphical format.

To get setup, do something like this:

```
...ruby_programs$ mkdir your_gem_name
...ruby_programs$ cd your_gem_name
```

That directory is where the guide is issuing the tree command:

```
...ruby_programs/your_gem_name$ tree
```

(At this point, your directory will be empty)

2) The guide shows two steps in one image:

```
...ruby_programs/your_gem_name$ gem build hola.gemspec
                                ...

...ruby_programs/your_gem_name$ gem install ./hola-0.0.0.gem
                                ...
```

Don't overlook the second install step.